# How to get a specified row using cUrl PHP

Tags: php, json, curl

Hey guys I use curl to communicate web external server, but the type of response is html, I was able to convert it to json code (more than 4000 row) but I have no idea how to get specified row which contains my result. Any idea ?

Here is my cUrl code :

```
require_once('getJson.php');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.reputationauthority.org/domain_lookup.php?ip=website.com&Submit.x=9&Submit.y=5&Submit=Search');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
$data = '<<<EOF'.$data.'EOF';
$json = new GetJson();
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
$res = json_encode($json->html_to_obj($data), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
$myArray = json_decode($res,true);
```

For getJson.php

```
class GetJson{

    function html_to_obj($html) {
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML($html);
        return $this->element_to_obj($dom->documentElement);
    }
    function element_to_obj($element) {
        if ($element->nodeType == XML_ELEMENT_NODE){                    
            $obj = array( "tag" => $element->tagName );
            foreach ($element->attributes as $attribute) {
                $obj[$attribute->name] = $attribute->value;
            }
            foreach ($element->childNodes as $subElement) {
                if ($subElement->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE) {
                    $obj["html"] = $subElement->wholeText;
                }
                else {
                    $obj["children"][] = $this->element_to_obj($subElement);
                }   
            }
            return $obj;
        }
    }
}
```

My idea is instead of Browsing rows to achieve lign 2175 (doing something like : $data['children'][2]['children'][7]['children'][3]['children'][1]['children'][1]['children'][0]['children'][1]['children'][0]['children'][1]['children'][2]['children'][0]['children'][0]['html'] is not a good idea to me), I want to go directly to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the HTML being returned has a consistent structure every time, and you just want one particular value from one part of it, you may be able to use regular expressions to parse the HTML and find the part you need. This is an alternative you trying to put the whole thing into an array. I have used this technique before to parse a HTML document and find a specific item. Here's a simple example. You will need to adapt it to your needs, since you haven't specified the exact nature of the data you're seeking. You may need to go down several levels of parsing to find the right bit:

```
$data = curl_exec($ch);
//Split the output into an array that we can loop through line by line
$array = preg_split('/\n/',$data);
//For each line in the output
foreach ($array as $element)
{
    //See if the line contains a hyperlink
    if (preg_match("/<a href/", "$element"))
    {
         ...[do something here, e.g. store the data retrieved, or do more matching to find something within it]...
    }

}
```